# expressjs is not asynchronously processing my requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, nonblocking

```
var data = import('./blahblah/data')
app.get('/data', data.getData)
app.listen(3000)
```

```
// blahblah/data:
exports.getData = function(req, res) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.send('test')
    }, 10000)
};
```

```
//code I use to test
for(var i = 0;i<10;i++){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/data',
      success: function(l){console.log(l);}
    });
}
```

If I send 10 simultaneous requests to this endpoint, then they only receive a reply one at a time 10 seconds apart, with the last request coming 110 seconds after the first request was sent. Aren't nodejs and express supposed to let other requests process when the other requests are running asynchronous code?

Comment: How is `getData` used in your express app?

Comment: I updated the post to show how its used. Its just attached to a GET endpoint.

Comment: What makes you think it's not working async?

Comment: when I send 10 requests they return one at a time 10 seconds after the previous request.

Comment: @James Probably the 110s part, i.e., the OP is expecting each request should receive its response ~10s after the appropriate request.

Comment: Are you sure that the requests are actually simultaneous, and it's not the tool you use to send them that blocks?

Comment: Your browser might cause this. There are some limits on active connections per host.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. But just in case I'm wrong, I'll add the code I use to test the endpoint.

Comment: Also the network tab shows all the requests going out at once. + the same thing happens when I test using curl.

Comment: @RyanWeinstein: I think the network tab might show when the request was issued, not necessarily when it was sent. And I think curl is blocking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is fine, probably something is wrong with the way you're testing it.

Please, make sure that you're sending your requests in parallel.

I tested your code with [`loadtest` utility](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest)

```
loadtest -n 10 -c 10 http://localhost:3000/data
```

and got expected results

```
Target URL:          http://localhost:3000/data
Max requests:        10
Concurrency level:   10
Agent:               none

Completed requests:  10
Total errors:        0
Total time:          10.050681130000001 s
```

Here is a code snipped I tested:

```js
var app = require('express')();
app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.send('test')
    },10000)
});
app.listen(3000)
```

**Update:**

Web browsers usually limit the number of parallel requests per host. I just tested it in my Google Chrome and it limited the number of parallel requests by 6:

[image]

Here is a detailed timing for one of delayed requests:

[image]

Looks like your browser have an even harsher limits.

Comment: I added the way I test to the post, can you see whats wrong with that?

Comment: That detail view with the "stalled" time is the perfect illustration!

Comment: yeah it was being stalled. For some reason my browser has some strict limits. Thanks for your help.